# Sending body in POST request in flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter

This is my body for sending data with POST request in postman, it working fine

```
{
    "title" : "test",
    "description" : "estt",
    "category" : "Health care",
    "imageCover" : "",
    "author" : "",
    "authorImageProfile" : "",
    "dayCount" : "10",
    "goals" : programGoals, --> List<String> programGoals = ["goal1","goal2","goal3"];
}
```

but, With flutter how can I send this goals array in the json body?
I tried to encode data or make it string but nothing worked.
Please let me know where is the problem and how can I send like this list to server from app.

```
["Goal1","Goal2","Goal3"]
```

This is my request in flutter (Map jsonMap)

```
jsonMap = {
      "title": itemTitle,
      "description": itemDescription,
      "category": category,
      "imageCover": "",
      "author": "",
      "authorImageProfile": "",
      "dayCount": "10",
      "goals": programGoals
    };
final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$localHost$url'),
          encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
          body: jsonMap);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just send it as a list

Comment: Not work,
List<String> is not subtype of 'String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the encode data.

Whenever we send a request to the server the data should be encoded (Stringified)

So here is the solution -

```
    jsonMap = {
          "title": itemTitle,
          "description": itemDescription,
          "category": category,
          "imageCover": "",
          "author": "",
          "authorImageProfile": "",
          "dayCount": "10",
          "goals": programGoals
        };
    String data_to_sent = jsonEncode(jsonMap);
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('$localHost$url'),
              encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
              body: data_to_sent);
```